# how to use @types/module in combination with with npm module that types are written for?

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm

This is just example of some module that I have in my project.

There is a https://github.com/mapbox/polylabel TypeScript type definitions for npm module polylabel. Now when i do install `npm install --save @types/polylabel` i got types but when i install `npm install --save polylabel` I got npm module it self.

So my question is how to import `polylabel` but for that module to use TypeScript type definitions from that `@types/polylabel`? Example:

```
import polylabel from "polylabel";

export default class SomeClass extends Base {

   console.log(polylabel(coordinates, 1.0))
}
```

Now this will not work since typescript will try to import function that is definition without functionality from module it self.

Should I include module it self in webpack it self or there is another way to do that? Webpack part:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  polylabel: 'polylabel'
}),
```

I hope that question is clear on what i am trying/need to resolve.

Comment: As long as you have your tsconfig setup to reference the @types directory, it will always use types if they are available. Sometimes npm packages will come packaged with type definitions but in a lot of cases, they don't. This is when you need to run the `npn install @types/<module> --save-dev`

Comment: @mwilson it is a little bit confusing since there are nunch of npm packages and then bunch of types written for them that are not included in package it self. and offten that definitions are not up to date with module it self.

Comment: @mwilson can you add your comment as answer please.

Comment: Yes, it is. It's an interesting take because types are relative to typescript and not everyone uses it. However, as movement towards ES6 and using things like TypeScript, the demand is continuing to grow. It's definitely not favorable in a TypeScript setup to use something that doesn't have types available. You can also checkout https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you have your `tsconfig.json` setup to reference the `@types` directory, it will always use types if they are available. Sometimes npm packages will come packaged with type definitions but in a lot of cases, they don't. This is when you need to run the `npn install @types/<module> --save-dev`

Example `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types" // <-- This guy
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "e2e"
  ]
}
```